# Having problem with Powershell script for VM Agent Status and WindowsAzureGuestAgent service

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine

My current code:

```
if ($VM.VMAgent.Statuses[0].DisplayStatus -eq "Not Ready") {
    Write-Host $VM.VMAgent.Statuses.Message
} else {
    Start-Service $AzureAgentServiceName
}
```

Scenario:
1. Check VM Agent status **Good** or **Not Good**, If VM Agent status **GOOD** not require to Start WindowsAzureGuestAgent service.
2. If VM Agent status **NOT GOOD** require to Start WindowsAzureGuestAgent service.

Problem now in my script:
I can't check the agent status is Good or not good to excute. Can anyone help me with the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a bit flawed.

You can check if agent is ready or not but you cannot start agent service if its not running.  The agent is needed for any post deployment OS changes including start service from outside VM.

Also if the VM is not running or agent not installed you cannot get VMAgent Statuses.